# Can the Galois representation on the $p$-adic Tate module of $E/\mathbf{Q}_p$ be recovered from the $p$-divisible group associated to the mod $p$ good reduction of $E$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, and $E/\mathbf{Q}_p$ and elliptic curve with good reduction $\bar E_p$. Can the Galois representation of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ given by the $p$-adic Tate module of $E$ be recovered from the Dieudonn\'e module associated to the $p$-divisible group $\bar E_p[p^\infty]$ of the reduction $\bar E_p$?

In case of ordinary reduction, can the [EDIT: possible] splitting of the $p$-torsion $E[p]$, as Galois module, be understood in terms of the Dieudonn\'e module of the $p$-torsion $\bar E_p[p]$?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you want to assume good ordinary reduction, since in the supersingular case we have $\overline{E}_p[p^{\infty}]=0$.

Comment: Wait, by $\bar E_p[p^\infty]$ I am not denoting the direct limit of the group of $\bar F_p$-valued points of the schemes $\bar E_p[p^n]$. Instead, I want to consider the Dieudonn\'e module associated to the $p$-divisible group of $\bar E_p$. This last object is and Ind-scheme (I think, whatever that means) over $F_p$ and whose definition I prefer not to give hear. This gadget is studied, if I get it right, through its Diedonn\'e module (Fontaine's great book on p-divisible (which I am totally not familiar with) group defines it for example).

Comment: Your question is basically: can you recover a $p$-divisible group over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ from its reduction mod $p$? In general, the answer is no, since the deformation space of a $p$-divisible group over $\mathbb{F}_p$ is positive dimensional. But if you impose additional conditions, like the curve being CM, then you might be able to cut out a $0$-dimensional sub-space of the deformation space and then find a unique lift over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. Just one more thing please: is asking to recover the p-adic Tate module of E (as Galois module) really the same as asking for the p-divisible group of the Neron model of E over Z_p. Or is it little less? This is not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: It's essentially the same, by Tate's theorem on the full faithfulness of Tate module functor.

Comment: I should also say, you can recover the $p$-divisible group over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ from the Dieudonne module, let's call it $M$, *plus* a certain direct summand $Fil^1M\subset M$. Roughly speaking, $M$ is the crystalline cohomology of $\overline{E}_p$ (or its dual, depending on your conventions), and it is canonically identified with the de Rham cohomology of the Neron model of $E$ over $\mathbb{Int}_p$. The direct summand $Fil^1M$ is then obtained from the de Rham filtration and completely determines the lift.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Int}$, read $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about the theorem saying that the natural map
$\rm{Hom}_{F_p}(\bar E_p)\otimes\mathbf{Z}_p\rightarrow\rm{Hom}_{D}(T_p(\bar E_p))$ is an isomorphism? (Here D is the Dieudonn\e' ring of $Z_p[F,V]/(FV-p)$, and $T_p(\bar E_p)$ is the Dieudonn\'e module of the p-divisible group of E[p^\infty])?

Comment: Thanks. I do not know any of this, and I will try to learn it. But let me point out that I am interested only in the Galois representation given by the genuine Tate module of E/Q_p. This should be the generic fiber of the p-divisible group of the Neron model of E. Or not? I want it just from the Dieudonn\'e module of $\bar E_p[p^\infty]$. I don't know if I am making sense now.

Comment: Last line of the second comment of mine above should be "p-divisible group of $\bar E_p[p^\infty]$". sorry about that

Comment: No, this is a different Tate's theorem! It says that the functor that takes a $p$-divisible group over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to its generic fiber is fully faithful. You cannot in general recover the $p$-divisible group of the Neron model just from the Dieudonne module associated with the special fiber; as I said, you need to take into account the extra information given to you by the Hodge filtration.

Comment: Ok, I see. I actually attended part of a seminar on this. Obviously, I did not get much from it. What reference would you recommend to read about it?